# How to change css style and add dynamic style to Vuesax vs-input?

Tags: css, vue.js, input, vuesax

I am using "**[vuesax](https://github.com/lusaxweb/vuesax)**": "3.11.1" in my VueJS project.

I can't find a way to change the border of the input of vs-input disabled.

```
<vs-input
  class="w-5/12 pr-5"
  disabled
  type="text"
  :placeHolder="timeConvert(info.delay_secs)"
  :style="getDelayColor(info.status_color)"
  label="Advance / Late"
/>
```

I tried applying an inline style (`style="border: 1px solid #ff0000;"`), but it gets applied to the whole component (the red one in the image attached), while I need to change the color of the border of the **input inside of it** (the green one in the image attached).
[image]

Inspecting the html it looks it is `vs-inputx vs-input--input normal`, but if I try adding css style to this class it doesn't work.

Same problem for adding dynamic style to it, using **:style** and passing a function to it (usual Vue way of doing it - it could also be written as `` :style="`color: ${info.status_color};`" ``). If I apply it to the vs-input it doesn't have effect. I don't know how to target the element inside of it (the green one in the image attached), because it's not in the template.

Is there **any expert of Vuesax library**?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also stacking same issue. Any response?

Comment: Unfortunately not, at the moment I can't check how I managed to sort it out, the code looks as the example, but can't see how it looks in the browser (need to run a service I do not have access to). Try upvoting the question so it get noticed and maybe it can reach someone else. As soon as I have the chance to look into it I will, and get back to you.